# LocalProxy.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unbound_message'

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I'm trying to build my application, after installing flask_login0.4.1 and configuring it
i come across this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\application.py", line 2, in <module>
    from wtform_fields import *
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\wtform_fields.py", line 6, in <module>
    from models import User
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_login import UserMixin
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_login\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>      
    from .login_manager import LoginManager
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_login\login_manager.py", line 24, in <module> 
    from .utils import (_get_user, login_url as make_login_url, _create_identifier,
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 13, in <module>
    from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp
ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_str_cmp' from 'werkzeug.security' (C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\security.py)
```

based on answers on stackoverflow I have downgraded werkzeug to 2.0.0 but i got other error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\application.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect,url_for
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import json as json
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>        
    from ..globals import current_app
  File "C:\Users\Catalyst\Desktop\Python\chatAp\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 56, in <module>
    app_ctx: "AppContext" = LocalProxy(  # type: ignore[assignment]
TypeError: LocalProxy.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unbound_message'
```

what other alternatives solutions I can use
I'm using flask 2.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Werkzeug <= 2.1.2   
flask == 2.1.2
```

Both of these have to be compatible. Let me know if you can work it out. the above version worked for me.